# Server fail to send data over 2992 port. Webpack, Flask, Apache

Tags: ubuntu, port

I am newbie to webpack, but desperately want to master this tech. 
I develop my web application with running flask app via python script `__init__.py` and by running webpack in cmd `npm run start`.

After bit of development is complete I execute `npm run build` and then push a whole folder `.build` to the Ubuntu server.

My project has the following structure:

```
├── api.log
├── app.py
├── assets
│   ├── images
│   ├── scripts
│   └── styles
├── build
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── public
├── db.log
├── flask_webpack_test.iml
├── __init__.py
├── node_modules
│   == bunch of them here
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── __pycache__
│   ├── api.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── app.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── config.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── db_connection.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── our_logging.cpython-35.pyc
├── templates
│   └── index.jinja2
├── tests
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_views.py
├── webpack.config.js
└── wsgi.py
```

But when I go to my domain name it displays only pure html without any static content.. 
In the web browser console I see `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

I copied the test project from [here](https://github.com/nickjj/flask-webpack/tree/master/flask_webpack/tests/test_app)

So connection is aborted through port 2992. On my Ubuntu Server I have opened it..

My manifest.json

```
{"assets":"images/dog/noidea.jpg":"images/dog/noidea.b9252d5fd8f39ce3523d303144338d7b.jp,
"app_css.css":"app_css.6e0ed0322fcd44592461.css",
"app_js.js":"app_js.3919e91e57e850f7cebe.js"},
"publicPath":"http://localhost/assets/"}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var ManifestRevisionPlugin = require('manifest-revision-webpack-plugin');

var rootAssetPath = './assets';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app_js: [
            rootAssetPath + '/scripts/entry.js'
        ],
        app_css: [
            rootAssetPath + '/styles/main.css'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: './build/public',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost/assets/',
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/i, loader: 'script-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg([\?]?.*))$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file?context=' + rootAssetPath + '&name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
                    'image?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css'),
        new ManifestRevisionPlugin(path.join('build', 'manifest.json'), {
            rootAssetPath: rootAssetPath,
            ignorePaths: ['/styles', '/scripts']
        })
    ]
};
```

And python file which gives an html:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

from flask_webpack import Webpack
webpack = Webpack()


def create_app(settings_override=None):
    """
    Create a test application.

    :param settings_override: Override settings
    :type settings_override: dict
    :return: Flask app

    """
    app = Flask(__name__)

    params = {
        'DEBUG': False,
        'WEBPACK_MANIFEST_PATH': './build/manifest.json'
    }

    app.config.update(params)

    # if settings_override:
    #     app.config.update(settings_override)

    webpack.init_app(app)

    return app


app = create_app()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.jinja2')


# @app.route('/s')
# def index():
#     return render_template('index.jinja2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
    # run_simple('localhost', 5000, app, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

Can anyone help to figure this out? What is wrong with my settings and why I cannot run webpack on my server?

**EDIT ONE**

```
ivan@194-58-97-122:~$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 194.58.97.122:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      303/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      303/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      303/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      326/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      303/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1500            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      355/ihttpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      302/mongod
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      385/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      303/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      326/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      303/named
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      385/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      335/mysqld
```

And firewall settings:

```
ivan@194-58-97-122:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2992                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2992/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
1191/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2992 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2992/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
1191/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: is port 2992 opened on your firewall / router?

Comment: Please, check out the Edit one

Comment: judging by your netstat output, nothing is listening on port 2992. are you starting whatever program should be listening on that port?

Comment: Honestly speaking, port 2992 is a mystery thing here since I have never used a webpack before. I just saw that it uses port 2992 for some reasons, so I opened it and not really sure what program or service is using this port...

Comment: judging by this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/ and comment contents from here https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask/issues/281 you have to start something to listen on that port.

Comment: Thank you! Can you advice some harmless service to run on this port?

Comment: I think you actually have to run the `webpack` to make it work, like in the first comment here: https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask/issues/281#issue-305075406